# How do I install a gem from a github repo with config.gem (rails 2.3.8)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

this is the error I'm getting:

```
 % rake gems:install
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
gem install deep_cloning --source https://DerNalia@github.com/DerNalia/deep_cloning.git
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'deep_cloning' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Not Found 404 (https://DerNalia@github.com/DerNalia/deep_cloning.git/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Obviously, I can't specify latest_specs at that URL in my code, as github urls organize thing in blobs...

This is how I'm trying to include the gem in my environment.rb file

```
  config.gem "deep_cloning",:source => "https://DerNalia@github.com/DerNalia/deep_cloning.git"
```

now, in bundler, it would be:

```
gem "deep_cloning", :git => "git://github.com/DerNalia/deep_cloning.git"
```

(which works)

But i'm using Rails 2.3.8, and one of the gems (attr_encrypted) doesn't work with bundler, so I am forced to use config.gem's for all of the gems...

How do I modify my config.gem line such that `rake gems:install` will download the .gem file from my github repository??

Comment: `config.gem` doesn't know how do that - fetching gems from a git repo is a bundler specific thing

Comment: oh. well that's disappointing. silly config.gem >_<